# Why do we store methods in a variable when using Tkinter in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I just started learning Tkinter and when thing that really stood out was

```
win=tkinter.Tk()
```

I mean from what it looks win is basically a reference for the main window we created but  this is the first time I have seen something like this since tk() is a method and not a class . I know that everything is an object in python eh but I am kinda confused , help me senpais ....

Comment: Tk is a class in the tkinter module.  win is therefore a Tk object.  `repr(root)`
shows: '<tkinter.Tk object .>'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do we store methods in a variable when using Tkinter in python?

This question doesn't make much sense. Most programs do not store *methods*.

Regardless, tkinter is no different than any other module in this regard: you save a reference to something when you need to refer to the object later or you need to prevent the garbage collector from collecting the object.

> I mean from what it looks win is basically a reference for the main window we created

That is correct. In your code example `win` is a reference to the root window, an instance of the `Tk` class.

> I have seen something like this since tk() is a method and not a class

That is not true. At least, not if you meant to say `Tk()`. `Tk` from the tkinter module is in fact a class. So in this case you are creating an instance of the `Tk` class.

Comment: oh thanks, I was confused because geek for geeks said that it is a method but we can't create objects of a method . So that means button, canvas and others are also classes ?

Comment: @SankalpBartwal: yes, `Canvas`, `Button`, `Label` are all classes.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter.Tk() is an object of type tkinter.Tk, not a method.

Comment: It's slightly more complicated. Classes are actually callables that act as a factory for new instances of themselves. See the [Python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).